# Mystery 18-pin and 10-pin Molex Plugs

Tags: connector, plug

I'm working with a system that has a pair of plugs that I'm not familiar with. They appear to be Molex Mini Fit Jr. style connectors (such as those used to provide power for PCIe devices that require extra power), but in an 18-pin and 10-pin type that I'm not familiar with.

Not that that's surprising as I'm only familiar with a handful of molex connectors, but I'm hoping someone can help me identify an exact part number so I know what I'm looking for. I've tried searching from the Molex web-site but it's not the most user-friendly and I couldn't seem to open documents for half of the possible matches.

Here's an image of the (possible) Molex plugs. Any help in identifying whether they're a standard part (and appropriate part numbers) would be greatly appreciated. Also, if they exist in black then that'd be ideal (dunno if they'd be a different part number?).

[image: (Possible) Molex Connectors]

Answer (score 1):

Well the second one looks a lot like the below, which I found using the search terms "molex catalog connector" and then browsing the Mini Fit Jr. range as suggested in your question.

You can [browse their PDF catalogue](http://www.molex.com/catalog/web_catalog/pdfs/E.pdf).

[image: Molex 5557]

This is from page 63 of the PDF above, their reference "MX10 E-63".  It is described as:

> 4.20mm (.165") Pitch 
>   Mini-Fit Jr.™ Crimp Terminal Housing Receptacle 
>   5557 Dual Row

This comes in an 18 way part also, which might be your first image.  Shopping questions are off-topic but you should be able to find more with these details.

Comment: That does look like exactly what I need for the 10-pin connection; I had a real hard time finding an image of the 10-pin arrangement to see if it matched, so this is great thanks! I still haven't been able to find an image for the 18-pin, but I can't imagine they'd be from a different series, so I'll order some up and report back!